# How to run Node.js with thread setting

Tags: node.js

I'm node developer. I have problem when node executed. It use a lot of CPU (I have 2 core of CPU). Then I open task manager to find the problem, I found 2 process of node (I understand, node will run thread equal to amount of CPU thread). 1st process use a lot of CPU while 2nd process use little. I kill 1st process and my program is run properly.
Can I run node with 1 thread? or How to decrease the consumption of CPU.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure both processes are from your application? Do you use an editor like Brackets, which is using a node-process for itself?

Comment: @FabioPoloni I use sublime as IDE and sails.js as a framework. I run it without other node application running.

Comment: Since you talk about "Task manager" I assume you're using Windows. Have you tried to open the filepath of the processes? You can do this using a right-click on the processes. I just want to make sure they're both from your application, since I *never* saw this behaviour before.

Comment: Node is single threaded, right?

Comment: @FabioPoloni Environment is Window 8.1 64bit with nodejs v. 0.10.30 32bit. I'm sure that 2 processes are from same application(I restart OS before run node application). I try to find the solution to run node with only 1 thread but not found.

Comment: So, node runs on only one thread unless you have spawned child process from within the app.